# How do implement my pic24 onto a pcb board?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pcb, microchip, development

I have a microstick development board for the pic24, shown [here](http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM240013-1#dtVideoContent). The microstick contains many other components and parts other than the pic24 that are used for voltage regulating, debuggers, etc. In the project that I am working on, we will eventually need to just have a surface mount package of the pic24 and solder it to a pcb. Will I be able to just take the surface mount package of it and put it on a pcb and have it work or will I need to add the rest of the components that the microstick development board contains?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to move every part from Microstick to your PCB but you'd need some. Minimum connections are given in the datasheet, for PIC24F16KL402 it's on page 21 -> http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/31037b.pdf . Also, if you want to run the micro from external clock/crystal you'd have to add that. Lastly, if you want to have a hookup for the debugger you'd have to add more stuff. All this can be learned from the datasheet and the set of docs called Family Reference Manual (FRM), linked from the product page of the micro of interest.

Comment: Could I get a surface mount package of the pic24 and attach it to an adapter so that I could use it with the microstick? I'd do this so that I could program it, and then remove it and solder it to my PCB?

Comment: Yes you can; however, programming in-circuit is preferable for development and small batches.